# Turning off marginpar (marginparwidth) while in multicols environment

Tags: latex

I'm trying to turn off marginpar when starting a new multicols environment with this:

```latex
\renewenvironment{multicols}[1]{%
  \let\oldmarginparwidth\marginparwidth 
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{0}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
}{%
  \end{multicols}%
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{\oldmarginparwidth}%
}
```

However, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: That's not going to change the text width, if that's what you want. The marginpars just hang on the side of the text, they don't influence its size or position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you've got there won't work mid-page, you need to use the changepage package to do that.

```
\usepackage{changepage}
```

I take it you're trying to take up the full width of the page. I nicked this from the tufte-latex class:

First, define an 'overhang' amount that'll be added to the textwidth at the beginning and subtracted at the end:

```
\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}
```

Then use \adjustwidth with the overhang amount when you want to remove marginpar space:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}
% This will be displayed full-width
\end{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}
```

As Damien pointed out, you can still use marginpars like this, they'll just exceed the pagewidth. \multicols will prevent you from using floats, however.

Hope that's what you need!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here, but generally marginpars aren't allowed in multicols already. From the multicol documentation:

> ...floats and marginpars are not allowed in the current implementation [This is dictated by lack of time. To implement ﬂoats one has to reimplement the whole LATEX output routine.].

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get it working by using the chngpage package and defining a new environment which sets/resets different values before/after that environment.

However, I still have a problem on the last page of each \chapter: [header width on the last page of the chapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829212/latex-header-width-on-the-last-page-of-the-chapter)