# header width on the last page of the chapter

Tags: latex

I'm trying to turn off marginpar when starting a new multicols environment with this new environment, which uses the multicols and chngpage packages:

```
\newenvironment{multi}[1]{%
\newlength{\newtextwidth}%
\setlength{\newtextwidth}{\marginparwidth}%
\addtolength{\newtextwidth}{-1cm}%
\addtolength{\headheight}{.5cm}%
\let\oldheadrule\headrule%
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\newtextwidth}%
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\newtextwidth}\begin{multicols}{#1}}%
{\end{multicols}\end{adjustwidth}}
```

Which works great:
[latex header http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/6757/screenshotewa.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/6757/screenshotewa.png)

Uhm, almost, since on the last page of the current chapter "Lorem ipsum" it behaves like I hadn't instruct it to: \addtolength{\headwidth}{\newtextwidth}:
[latex header at the end of the chapter http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6072/screenshotwbd.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6072/screenshotwbd.png)

How could I fix that?

**Edit**:

I'm also using fancyhdr.

**2nd Edit**:

A PoC:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks,pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,bookmarksopen,backref
,colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}

\rhead{\large\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \huge\bfseries
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\sffamily\raggedleft\footnotesize #1]%
{\sffamily\raggedright\footnotesize
\begin{boxedminipage}{\marginparwidth}#1\end{boxedminipage}
}}




\newenvironment{multi}[1]{%
\newlength{\newtextwidth}%
\setlength{\newtextwidth}{\marginparwidth}%
\addtolength{\newtextwidth}{-1cm}%
\addtolength{\headheight}{.5cm}%
\let\oldheadrule\headrule%
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\newtextwidth}%
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\newtextwidth}\begin{multicols}{#1}}%
{\end{multicols}\end{adjustwidth}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{multi}{2}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{multi}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{multi}{2}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{multi}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{multi}{2}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{multi}


\end{document}
```

It should be possible to continue single-column on the same page, after "multi", but the headers must be kept like when the page was started within the "multi" environment.

Why would I need single-column after multi-column on the same page with a marginpar? Imagine presenting the source code for the article, with small hints on the margin. (That's what the listing package is there for)

Comment: It might help to show a complete LaTeX example, including all the packages you use - e.g. \headwidth is defined in fancyheadings, not in base LaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect your last heading box is being constructed after your text finishes making the multicol boxes, so you're out of the scope of your change.  It goes back to the old value.

You'd probably do well to add the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/) package and use it.  I believe it's well-behaved in multicolumn.

Okay, so it's almost certainly the scope thing.  You're doing the adjustwidth in your new `multi` environment.   When your text runs out in the multi envirnment, you haven't filled the last page; headers aren't set up until the page is filled.  So your mutlti environment finishes the box, you leave the scope, and THEN the page is finished and emitted.  Using the old width.

Set the header width and parameters outside the environment.

Comment: This is surely the right explanation. If you don't want to use fancyhdr, you could try a \clearpage at the end of the text. That might fake it.

Comment: The example I have exposed already uses fancyhdr. Sorry for missing to point that out.

Comment: Charlie, you have 19k rep and you have to ask about drive-by downvoters?

Answer (score 5):

I ran your test document.  It seems to have a bug in that `\newlength{\newtextwidth}` has a global effect, and so causes an error.  Not sure why that is but I pulled it out of the `\newenvironment{multi}` with no ill effect.

Charlie's diagnosis is definitely correct.  An alternative solution is to end the page after the multicols but before the adjustwidth, thus:

```
\newenvironment{multi}[1]{%
   ...}
{\end{multicols}\vfill\break\end{adjustwidth}}
```

I have tested this solution and on your sample document, it produces good output.

Comment: I second that; changing the width of the header from inside an environment should not work; what is TeX supposed to do when you have two environments on a single page which can't agree on the width? Also, when reordering content to fill pages perfectly, an environment could end up on a different page and when the header.